# Removing list of vms in vagrant cache

Tags: vagrant

I'm not looking for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15408969/how-do-i-destroy-a-vm-when-i-deleted-the-vagrant-file) answer, because my question is different.

When I type `vagrant global-status` I get a list of vms, but some of those directories and VMs have been deleted along with the Vagrantfiles.

But when i type `vagrant destroy [machineid]`, *I get the following error, which I am looking to resolve. Please advise.*

```
The working directory for Vagrant doesn't exist! This is the
specified working directory:

/Users/steven/projects/php/vagrant-laravel
```

Answer (score 252, accepted):

You should use the following command to remove invalid entries from the global index:

```
vagrant global-status --prune
```

Comment: Well, nice that it is an accepted and upvoted answer, but this "prunes" the global-status list. Meaning that the VM no longer shows up in the list. The VM itself remains untouched, though. Meaning one still has to unregister and delete it manually. The very simple thing should be that vagrant does its job properly when given `$ vagrant destroy -f <id>`

Comment: The output of `vagrant global-status --prune` is correct to not be aware of deleted Vagrant directories as Vagrant's knowledge of the VM it managed in that directory was removed when its files managing the VM were. It's the hypervisor's problem now.

Answer (score 17):

I had this issue as well.  I was able to fix it by modifying the contents of `~/.vagrant.d/data/machine-index/index`. It's in JSON format so I just removed the data related to instances that no longer existed.

I only removed the data that pertained to instances that no longer exist. I wouldn't modify any data that relates to an instance that exists in the file system.

Comment: I found this useful for just clearing the global-status boxes, which are usually off when I restart the host (my mac). It makes me wonder what the global-status does and if it has an affect on up'ing the box again.

Answer (score 16):

`--prune` didn't work for me. I removed `~/.vagrant`, `~/.vagrant.d` and `.vagrant`. And manually removed lingering VMs.

I migrated back `gems` and `boxes` from original `~/.vagrant.d`. Perhaps one can try only removing machine from `.vagrant` but I didn't test that.

Comment: I had this issue when the directory that the vagrant image was stared in had been deleted. --prune failed but rm -rf ~/.vagrant* worked. Running vagrant global-status after recreated the appropriate directories. (This removes all downloaded boxes to they will be re-downloaded on next vagrant up as needed)

Answer (score 3):

Use `vagrant box remove -f [name]`

It works. Guaranteed!

Answer (score 0):

I used

```
vagrant global-status --prune
vagrant box remove -f [name]
```

Also I removed

```
~/.vagrant, ~/.vagrant.d and .vagrant.
```

And manually removed lingering VMs if exists.

Answer (score 0):

I am working on windows powershell
when vagrant global-status --prune not allow.
debug by this command:
`vagrant global-status --prune --debug`
look for your path of vagrant.d

my situation

`INFO global: VAGRANT_HOME="F:\Vagrant\vagrant.d"`

`delet F:\Vagrant\vagrant.d\data\machine-index*`

"vagrant global-status" again will clear all cache.

maybe linux had same file in machin-index.
you can try it.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).